# Counting along columns in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which contains a column with Names, and then columns containing either the value Yes, No or NaN next to these names. What steps would I take to count the amount of times Yes, No or NaN appears beside each name across each column? To give you a better example of what I mean:

```
col1    col2  col3  col4
Bob       yes   yes   no
Tim       no     no   yes
Susan     yes   Nan   yes
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you add your intended output ?

Answer (score 3):

One possible idea using [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) along with [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
counts = (
    df.set_index('col1').astype(str).stack()
    .groupby(level=0, sort=False).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
)
```

Another possible solution using [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
counts = df.set_index('col1').astype(str).stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
```

Result:

```
# print(counts)
       nan  no  yes
col1               
Bob      0   1    2
Tim      0   2    1
Susan    1   0    2
```

Comment: why `.astype(str)` ?

Comment: @Datanovice If there is `NaN` it gets dropped while using `stack`..

Comment: @Datanovice I guess is to convert `nan` to `'Nan'` so `stack` don't skip them. One can pass `dropna=False` to `stack` instead.